# How to get a JavaFX MenuItem to respond to a TAB KeyPress?

Tags: javafx

A JavaFX MenuItem can respond to most KeyPress events by setting an ActionEvent EventHandler. However, while the event handler does catch a KeyPress of KeyCode.ENTER, it does *not* catch a KeyCode.TAB KeyPress event.  Apparently, some key events like TAB are handled at a deeper level.  For example, the arrow keys enable traversal of the menu.

My ContextMenu is a list of completions of an email address string the user has started typing in a TextField.   The users want to press the arrow keys to select the desired item, and the TAB key to execute the completion.

I can attach an event handler to the ContextMenu itself and catch the TAB keypress. But the event's Source is then the ContextMenu, and I can find no variables in the ContextMenu indicating which MenuItem was highlighted when the TAB key was pressed. MenuItem allows css style to control appearance of the menu item in focus, but it does not have any properties telling whether it is in focus or not.

I have tried futzing with the EventDispatchChain via MenuItem buildEventDispatchChain() to no avail. There seems to be no way to intercept the TAB KeyPress or otherwise determine which menu item was in focus when the TAB key was pressed.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If you got that far to intercept the TAB keypress on the menu level, who prevented you from storing the latest focussed MenuItem and fire the action for that one (if it is not null)? E.g. attach a focus listener to each MenuItem, if the item gets focussed, so you know what to fire later on..

Comment: I was not able to intercept the TAB keypress on the menu level.  I see no way to attach a focus listener to MenuItems.  MenuItems are not Nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get this right, you want to override the default keypressed listener to add your own response, so for that we have to find where it's applied.

To get this working, we've got to get our hands dirty with private API...

`ContextMenu` skin (`ContextMenuSkin`) uses a `ContextMenuContent` object, as a container with all the items. Each of these items are also in a `ContextMenuContent.MenuItemContainer` container.

We can override the keypressed listener on the parent container, while we can add a focusedProperty listener to the items on the items container.

Using this private API

```
import com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ContextMenuContent;
```

this is working for me:

```
private ContextMenuContent.MenuItemContainer itemSelected=null;

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    MenuItem cmItem1 = new MenuItem("Item 1");
    cmItem1.setOnAction(e->System.out.println("Item 1"));
    MenuItem cmItem2 = new MenuItem("Item 2");
    cmItem2.setOnAction(e->System.out.println("Item 2"));

    final ContextMenu cm = new ContextMenu(cmItem1,cmItem2);

    Scene scene = new Scene(new StackPane(), 300, 250);
    scene.setOnMouseClicked(t -> {
        if(t.getButton()==MouseButton.SECONDARY || t.isControlDown()){
            cm.show(scene.getWindow(),t.getScreenX(),t.getScreenY());

            ContextMenuContent cmc= (ContextMenuContent)cm.getSkin().getNode();

            cmc.setOnKeyPressed(ke->{
                switch (ke.getCode()) {
                    case UP:    break;
                    case DOWN:  break;
                    case TAB:   ke.consume();
                                if(itemSelected!=null){
                                    itemSelected.getItem().fire();
                                }
                                cm.hide();
                                break;
                    default: break;
                }
            });
            VBox itemsContainer = cmc.getItemsContainer();
            itemsContainer.getChildren().forEach(n->{
                ContextMenuContent.MenuItemContainer item=(ContextMenuContent.MenuItemContainer)n;
                item.focusedProperty().addListener((obs,b,b1)->{
                    if(b1){
                        itemSelected=item;
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    });

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Comment: The important thing here is that the ContextMenu had to have been visible once for the skin not to be `null`, or assigned a skin manually. Threw me of there for a second.

Answer (score 1):

Excellent! Thank you @jose! I ended up writing somewhat different code but 
the key is using com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ContextMenuContent, which provides 
access to the ContextMenuContent.MenuItemContainer objects that hold the MenuItems.

In order to not break the existing UP/DOWN key behavior, I added a new handler
to the ContextMenuContent object; this handler only consumes the TAB KeyPress and 
everthing else passes through to their normal handlers.

Looking at the ContextMenuContent class, I borrowed their existing method for
finding the focused item, so didn't have to add focusedProperty listeners.

Also, I'm on Java 1.7 and don't have lambdas and I use a very basic programming style.

```
public class MenuItemHandler_CMC <T extends Event> implements EventHandler {
    public ContextMenuContent m_cmc;

    public AddressCompletionMenuItemHandler_CMC(ContextMenuContent cmc){
        m_cmc = cmc;
    }

    @Override
    public void handle(Event event){
        KeyEvent ke = (KeyEvent)event;
        switch(ke.getCode()){
        case TAB: 
            ke.consume();
            MenuItem focused_menu_item = findFocusedMenuItem();
            if(focused_menu_item != null){
                focused_menu_item.fire();
            }
            break;
        default: break;
        }
    }

    public MenuItem findFocusedMenuItem() {
        VBox items_container = m_cmc.getItemsContainer();
        for (int i = 0; i < items_container.getChildren().size(); i++) {
            Node n = items_container.getChildren().get(i);
            if (n.isFocused()) {
                ContextMenuContent.MenuItemContainer menu_item_container = (ContextMenuContent.MenuItemContainer)n;
                MenuItem menu_item = menu_item_container.getItem();
                return menu_item;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

...Attach the additional handler

```
    if(m_context_menu.getSkin() != null){
        ContextMenuContent cmc = (ContextMenuContent)m_context_menu.getSkin().getNode();
        MenuItemHandler_CMC menu_item_handler_cmc = new MenuItemHandler_CMC(cmc);
        cmc.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, menu_item_handler_cmc);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @EricSaund for posting back your solution. I didn't consume the event with up/down keys, so it wasn't overriden. I included it on the switch in case you wanted to implement some custom behavior.